# Qt event regain focus MainWindow

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I need to handle some stuffs when my main window regain the focus (when i close a child window).

But i didn't found how do that.

Someone can help me?

Thanks

Comment: Stephen Chu's right. See this answer for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29059371/1724702

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-implement [`changeEvent()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#changeEvent) of your main window or install an [event filter](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#installEventFilter) to it, and watch for `ActivationChange` event.