# in Qt, what QEvent means loses window focus, regain window focus? (Set transparency)

Tags: qt

I need to set transparency when my application loses focus.
I also need to reset the transparency when it regains focus (from a mouse click or alt-tab or whatever)

I know how to set the transparency, so that is not the issue:
setWindowOpacity(0.75);

The issue is WHEN?

Comment: an almost solution was to use the enterEvent and leaveEvent, but that had nothing to do with focus only when the mouse left

Answer (score 5):

I agree with Kévin Renella that there are sometimes issues with `QWidget::focusInEvent` and `QWidget::focusOutEvent`. Instead, a better approach would be to implement `QWidget::changeEvent()`:

```
void MyQWidget::changeEvent(QEvent *event)
{   
    QWidget::changeEvent(event);
    if (event->type() == QEvent::ActivationChange)
    {
        if(this->isActiveWindow())
        {
            // widget is now active
        }
        else
        {
            // widget is now inactive
        }
    }
}
```

You can also achieve the same thing by installing an `event-filter`. See [The Event System](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html) on Qt Documentation for more information.

Answer (score 1):

When a [QFocusEvent](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qfocusevent.html) event occurs. Just re-implement

```
void QWidget::focusInEvent ( QFocusEvent * event );
void QWidget::focusOutEvent ( QFocusEvent * event );
```

from [QWidget](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qwidget.html#focusOutEvent). Make sure to always call the super-class method before or after doing your work. i.e., (before case)

```
void Mywidget::focusInEvent (QFocusEvent * event ){
   QWidget::focusInEvent(event);
   // your code
}
```

But, there are sometimes issues with `QWidget::focusInEvent` and `QWidget::focusOutEvent`. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29059371/1724702) for a more reliable approach.

Comment: class DockStartStop : public QDockWidget

Answer (score 1):

There are sometimes issues with `QWidget::focusInEvent` and `QWidget::focusOutEvent` events of `QWidget`

There is an alternative using `QWidget::windowActivationChange(bool state)`. True, your widget is active, false otherwise.